# Return value from combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

**How do you return the value selected in this combobox?**

```py
combobox_label = tk.Label(top_level, text="How many marks?", font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))

combobox= ttk.Combobox(top_level)

combobox['values'] = [int(i) for i in range(0, marks+1)]

combobox_label.pack()

combobox.pack()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the Combobox widget? The `get` method is documented.

Answer (score -1):

you need to put textvariable inside Combobox

```
value_for_combobox = ttk.StringVar()
combobox_label = ttk.Combobox((top_level, text="How many marks?", textvariable = value_for_combobox )
```

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't seem to be working, it gets rid of the drop-down list???

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a textvariable since the combobox itself has a `get` method.

Comment: This could would give an error as `(` is not closed

Comment: also I am pretty sure that `ttk` doesn't have a `StringVar` or any `Variable` for that matter

Comment: @Matiiss ur wrong

Comment: No, I'm not. You, on the other hand, are, in fact, wrong about me being wrong because `tkinter.ttk` (`ttk`) doesn't actually have a `StringVar` attribute or any of the similar `Variable` attributes that `tkinter` has